# Passing arguments to msi

Tags: chocolatey

In [chocolatey documentation](https://chocolatey.org/docs/commands-install) they state that in order to pass parameters to MSI need to use following argument:

> --ia, --installargs, --installarguments, --install-arguments=VALUE
>        InstallArguments - Install Arguments to pass to the native installer in 
>          the package. Defaults to unspecified.

I tried that assuming that it will be automatically appended to MSI execution but parameters were not passed.

Then I looked in chocolateyinstall.ps1 I have, and I noticed silentArgs parameter that has default initialization which looks like exactly arguments that passed to MSI. I tried to remove it with hope it will pass parameters to MSI but still no luck.

So the question is: how do I pass parameters from command line to MSI when using cinst or choco install?

Here is my chocolateyinstall.ps1 which is pretty standard:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; # stop on all errors
$toolsDir   = "$(Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition)"
$packageArgs = @{
  packageName   = $env:ChocolateyPackageName
  unzipLocation = $toolsDir
  fileType      = 'msi'
  file          = Get-Item $toolsDir\*.msi
  checksumType  = 'sha256' #default is md5, can also be sha1, sha256 or sha512
  # MSI
  silentArgs    = "/qn /norestart /l*v `"$($env:TEMP)\$($packageName).$($env:chocolateyPackageVersion).MsiInstall.log`""
  validExitCodes= @(0, 3010, 1641)
}

Install-ChocolateyPackage @packageArgs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let take for example the installation of the Chocolatey GUI package, which also uses an MSI.  If you run the following command:

```
choco install chocolateygui --install-arguments="'/forcerestart'"
```

This additional argument will be passed to the underlying MSI, which will cause the machine to be rebooted when the installation of the MSI is completed.

**NOTE:** This will have the side effect of not completing the Chocolatey installation, so the package will not actually be marked as installed.  This was just an example of augmenting the parameters passed to the MSI.

Another example would be to run the following:

```
choco install chocolateygui --install-arguments="'/forcerestart'" --override-arguments
```

The second parameter, `--override-arguments` causes only the arguments that are passed in to be respected.  Doing this causes the installation to block, since the silent arguments have been removed from the package.

So, long story short, it sounds like what you are doing is exactly correct.  If you can share the exact command that you are trying to use, it might help to figure out what is going on.

**As a side note**, looks like you are creating an embedded Chocolatey Package, meaning that the MSI is actually contained within the nupkg file.  This is perfectly valid, however, you should be using `Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage` (https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-install-package), rather than `Install-ChocolateyPackage` (https://chocolatey.org/docs/helpers-install-chocolatey-package)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I execute my package like so: "choco install C:\mypackage.nupkg -y --install-arguments=/q". As a result, I do see UI (my MSI has UI) while I expect it to proceed without. I tried also with --override-arguments and changed the command to Install-ChocolateyInstallPackage - but still, no luck

Comment: If you pass that command line argument directly to the MSI, i.e. outside of Chocolatey, does the installation proceed silently?  You should be able to review the Chocolatey log file to see exactly how the arguments are received, and ultimately passed to the MSI.

Comment: if I execute "msiexec /i c:\mypackage.msi /q" then I get the desired result. Btw, from the choco result in command line I don't see that parameters are appended to MSI file

Comment: Can you try something... you shouldn't do choco install path_to_nupkg, instead, do choco install mypackage --source path_to_nupkg_folder.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Wonder why is it different than executing package directly from the file...

Comment: That is a known issue that you should not specify a source to the nupkg as it overrides other things - it should throw a warning that you did when that occurs to let you know it is going to possibly mess other things up.